# Is there certain functionality JDBC driver from MYSQL does not have?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jdbc

I am trying to find the type of data that a column is through the JDBC driver from MYSQL.

The query I am trying to execute is `SHOW FIELDS FROM PARAMETERS WHERE FIELD='COLUMN_NAME'` through Java and and the exception thrown is a `java.sql.SQLException` with the following error: `Before Start of Result set`. I am positive I am executing the same query as the one I am doing through SQL. Is there any other way of retrieving the column type with **just the column name**

Comment: It sounds like you are getting a result set back. What is the rest of the code. I suspect it's in monkeying with the cursor to read the result set that you are throwing this error as the SQL statement is fine and the result set sounds like it exists.

Comment: Did you remember to call `rs.next();` before trying to read (the first row of) the results?

Comment: You guys are very right, I have been coding for about 5 hours now with many requests to mysql and forgot to include the next(). Thanks for your help @GordThompson